# Completing code block with semicolon in intellij java

Tags: intellij-idea, reformatting

I'm tired of having to take time to reformat code after every statement. Call me lazy or call me spoiled, but every IDE I've used reformatted code automatically when I entered a semicolon.

I've been using intellij because eclipse and android studio have too many internal dependencies that cause problems. But it doesn't reformat code the way the other two do. Is there a plugin or method I could use to correct this?

Comment: Code completion also stops when entering {

Comment: See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried by myself but the following could address the problem with automatic re-format:

- activate the option "save file automatically if the application is
  idle for..." option in IntelliJ Idea Settings
- install and configure the save actions plugin
  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions

Regarding Eclipse (I didn't use it for a long time) wasn't automatic reformat of the code triggered on file save? You said you had in eclipse this support on entering a semicolon.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Also try shift-ctrl-enter. This completes the line, adding semi-colon, closing brackets etc but as a side effect also reformats the line.